# Does anyone have all of Paul Wilmott's "Spreadsheets and VBA" files?

Tags: modeling, excel, vba

I couldn't find it on his website and the only ones I have are the files contained in the Introduction to Quantitative Finance's CD.

Comment: are these freely available or is distributing them illegal due to copyright?

Comment: I have no idea, if there is a way to buy it from a licenced stored I would like to know, but there where no mention of these spreadsheets on his website,